# Running find...exec tar czvf only archives one file...need all files

Tags: tar, gzip, redhat-enterprise-linux, logfiles

When attempting to run

```
find . -iname "*.gz" -mtime +7 -exec tar czvf all_gizip_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz {} \;
```

I get the list of files

```
./corosync.log-20140620.gz
./corosync.log-20140618.gz
./rgmanager.log-20140620.gz
./fenced.log-20140620.gz
./rgmanager.log-20140618.gz
./qdiskd.log-20140618.gz
```

But the archive only gets the last item

```
 tar -tvf all_gizip_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root       506 2014-06-18 03:21 ./qdiskd.log-20140618.gz
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like the find is limiting to the last 7 days, do the files meet that criteria?

Comment: Yes Tyson. Log rotate creates the .gz to start with. I need to run the second in cron to take all gz's and put them into a single gz and then move them off to archive. jjlin gave me the correction to my original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command is running `tar` once for each file, and each call to `tar` creates an output of the same name, thus overwriting the previous output. So you end up with only the last file. You need something like

```
find . -iname "*.gz" -mtime +7 | xargs tar czvf all_gizip_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz
```

This should work fine as long as your list of files isn't huge. If it is, then you'll probably want to switch to using `tar rvf` and doing a separate `gzip` step at the end.